# How do I remove "Activities" button from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, button, activities-overview

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I don't like the button "*Activities*" at the top left of the screen. Is it possible to remove it completely? If not, can I remove the word, leaving the button's action there?

Comment: @PRATAP I can't find this program on ubuntu software. I installed Gnome Tweaks but the option "Activities Overview Hot Corner" does not change anything when turned on/off.